# Mouse cursor scaling issues in Xubuntu 14.04 with XFCE 4.10

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xubuntu, xfce4

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 with XFCE 4.10 and I just recently bought a Seiki 39' 4K display for home. While I think that the display itself is working great so far and I love it, I am noticing some small quirks with the window manager or the desktop (I'm not sure exectly which).

One of these quirks is that the mouse cursor changes sizes depending on what it is hovering over on the screen. See below a few different examples on Thunderbird, Chrome and over the desktop.

[image: Thunderbird]

[image: Chrome]

[image: Desktop]

I didn't have this cursor scaling issue when I used a 1080p (1920x1080) screen and it started to happen when I connected the 4K screen. Is there a way for me to configure a uniform cursor size across all screens?

Comment: Same issue here. I have a dual monitor setup as well and I can't get it to work properly. I can either use only the 4K or use my other monitor with the setting "same". But I can not have dual displays *and* two different resolutions.

Comment: Seems to still be an issue... four years later..

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04.1 running on a Dell m3800 connected to a U2713HM monitor. Installing [Infinality](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html) to get better font rendering makes this issue go away. This is of course not a fix for the issue but just a workaround. Hopefully this works for Xubuntu 14.04 also.

Comment: For these purposes, generally, Ubuntu and Xubuntu are the same thing. The difference is mainly the window manager that is selected by default (Xubuntu uses Xfce as default, hence the X in the name).